# Lua add key value pair into table (array)

Tags: lua

In my Lua project I receive an array, encode it into JSON and pass further. My Lua encode function looks like the following:

```
local function encode_table(val, stack)

  local res = {}
  stack = stack or {}

  -- Circular reference?
  if stack[val] then error("circular reference") end

  stack[val] = true

  if val[1] ~= nil or next(val) == nil then
    -- Treat as array -- check keys are valid and it is not sparse
    local n = 0

    for k in pairs(val) do

      if type(k) ~= "number" then
        error("invalid table: mixed or invalid key types")
      end
      n = n + 1
    end
    -- need to add a stub somewhere here above the next line
    if n ~= #val then
      error("invalid table: sparse array") -- THIS TRIGGERS and stops the code
    end
    -- Encode
    for i, v in ipairs(val) do
      table.insert(res, encode(v, stack))
    end
    stack[val] = nil
    return "[" .. table.concat(res, ",") .. "]"

  else
    -- Treat as an object
    for k, v in pairs(val) do

      if type(k) ~= "string" then
        error("invalid table: mixed or invalid key types")
      end

      table.insert(res, encode(k, stack) .. ":" .. encode(v, stack))
    end
    stack[val] = nil
    return "{" .. table.concat(res, ",") .. "}"
  end
end
```

The problem is that I reveive an array with a 1 element missing. I need to add a stub for it in a key - value manner, say

```
myArray['missingKey'] = 'somestubvalue'
```

but I donk know how to do that. Also there is a check in the code for sparse array and this check throws an error, so I need to add a stub before this check is done (pls see the code). Any ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: In other words, you want to successfully convert Lua arrays with nils inside to JSON?  There are a lot of libraries for this ([example](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua)). `local json = require'json'; print(json.encode({11, nil, 22, 33}))`

Comment: yes, maybe something like that but the problem is I am working with 3rd party services and I need to encode a received array with some mandatory fields missing. In other words I need to replace `nil` with some stub value and give an encoded array further. I have already found a clue but thank you for your response, will try this library later on.